# How to send query from js code using ajax to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an event, When I clicking right button on the marker `google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', (function (marker) {` **it returns function:** `return function () { marker.setMap(null); delete markerBusyBrID[this.marker]; deleteBrigade(); //As I think I need something here to start my ajax query }` in that code I need to send request to ajax
Here is a part of code:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', (function (marker) {
                return function () {
                    marker.setMap(null);
                    delete markerBusyBrID[this.marker];
                    deleteBrigade();
  //here must be start of my ajax query
                }
```

My servlet name `getChangeBrigadeStatus`
and my parameter which I need to send `brigadeNumber`
I don't understand how to send ajax query.

Comment: Is `deleteBrigade` async?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Can you paste the code for the `deleteBrigade` function? It's important to know what that is

Comment: `deleteBrigade = function (map) {
                var i = allBusyBrigades.length - 1;
                if (i >= 0) {
                    allBusyBrigades[i].setMap(map);
                    allBusyBrigades.pop();
                    allBrigadeNumbers.pop();
                    brigadeCount(1);
                }
            };`

Comment: do you need the code inside the $('#deleteBrigadeButton').click callback to  ALSO execute after `marker.setMap(null);
                    delete markerBusyBrID[this.marker];
                    deleteBrigade();` ?

Comment: No I need a code after `marker.setMap(null); delete markerBusyBrID[this.marker]; deleteBrigade();` to execute the code in `$('#deleteBrigadeButton')`

Comment: All the `if(!allBrigadeNumbers.length==0){
        var brigadeNumber = allBrigadeNumbers[allBrigadeNumbers.length-1];
    }
    $.get('getChangeBrigadeStatus', {brigadeNumber: brigadeNumber}, function () {
    });` stuff to execute after `marker.setMap(null);
                    delete markerBusyBrID[this.marker];
                    deleteBrigade();` ?

Comment: a little bit different. I have a event, When I clicking right button on the marker `google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', (function (marker) {` it returns function: `return function () {
                    marker.setMap(null);
                    delete markerBusyBrID[this.marker];
                    deleteBrigade();
  //As I think I need something here to start my ajax query
                }`
                after that I need to send request to ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Till I waited for answers and help I have looked to another topics. And one new topic has pushed me to the answer and it's so easy.

here is a code:

```
               google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', (function (marker) {
                return function () {
                    marker.setMap(null);
                    delete markerBusyBrID[this.marker];
                    deleteBrigade();
                    $.get('getChangeBrigadeStatusFreeFromBrigade', {brigadeNumber: brigadeNumber}, function () {
                    });
```

But this code will help me in other things which I also didn't knew how to solve

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand but if what you want is ajax request to be made after certain functions are done you can try something like this

the request will only be sent if all functions are triggered 
of course you can add parameters and modify `sendTheRequest()` as you wish

, hope it helps

```
var fs = [];
function sendTheRequest(){
    if (fs.length == 2) {
        fs = [];
        //send it
    }
}
function fun1(){
    //code
    fs[0] = 1;
    sendTheRequest();
}
function fun2(){
    //code
    fs[1] = 1;
    sendTheRequest();
}
```

Comment: But how to send the request to ajax ?

Comment: I have a event, When I clicking right button on the marker `google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', (function (marker) {` it returns function: `return function () { marker.setMap(null); delete markerBusyBrID[this.marker]; deleteBrigade(); //As I think I need something here to start my ajax query }` after that I need to send request to ajax

Comment: check [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/) it may help
and here is a simple example
===
`requestUrl = 'www.smthing.com/deleteBrigade';`
`$.ajax({
   url: requestUrl,
   type: 'get',
    data: 'bridigateId='+id,
    dataType: 'json', // set response to be json
    success: function(output){
        //success code
    }
});`

Answer (score 0):

Create a function called `deleteBrigade` and use it for both spots

```
// this function will be reused for the click event handler
// and also for being executed at the end, inside your google maps event right click handler
function deleteBrigade() {
  if(!allBrigadeNumbers.length==0){
      var brigadeNumber = allBrigadeNumbers[allBrigadeNumbers.length-1];
  }
  $.get('getChangeBrigadeStatus', {brigadeNumber: brigadeNumber}, function () {
    // something here
  });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#deleteBrigadeButton').click(deleteBrigade);
});


//... wherever this is
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', (function (marker) {
  return function () {
      marker.setMap(null);
      delete markerBusyBrID[this.marker];
      deleteBrigade();
  }
})
```

Comment: It's not what I needed